# Why view parameter does not work on CouchDB REST API and Python module?

Tags: python, couchdb

I'm trying to get changes of documents in a specific DB's view.

In REST API I call for instance:

```
[GET] /users/_changes?view=my_custom_view
```

It returns all the documents not the one in `my_custom_view` view.

In `Python` I do the below:

```
results = collection.changes(include_docs=True, since=user_last_record, 
view='my_custom_view')
```

It also returns the whole documents! This is bizarre while in the [couchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/changes.html#db-changes) it is being said that:

> **view (string)** – Allows to use view functions as filters. Documents
>   counted as “passed” for view filter in case if map function emits at
>   least one record for them. See _view for more info.

When I use `couchDB's dashboard` to fetch documents based on `view` it works as expected, but not on API side!